# How do I get a random item in a nested list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am trying to have 2 values assigned to each key. I'm not sure how to access just one value in the key.

I want to display the shop value of each item, the second item in the list, randomly. Eg. printing `s1` might give `10` if it randomly choose the key "Tomato".
Here is the code:

```
import random

# Shop Key {[item:[cost, value]
shop = {"Tomato": [random.randint(4, 6), 10], "Loaf of Bread": [random.randint(9, 11), 20],
    "Banana": [random.randint(6, 8), 15], "Apple": [random.randint(3, 5), 8]}
s1 = random.choice(list(shop.keys()))
print(s1)
s2 = random.choice(list(shop.keys()))
print(s2)
s3 = random.choice(list(shop.keys()))
print(s3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear you are assigning one value to each key. The value is a list that contains two things, "cost" and "value".

`s1 = random.choice(list(shop.keys())` randomly selects a key from your dictionary, `shop`. To retrieve the value associated with the key you can use `s1_cost, s1_value = shop[s1]` or `s1_cost, s1_value = shop.get(s1)`.

To retrieve a random item from the list you can use `random.choice(shop[s1])`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I added clarifications to my new edit. I will try what you suggested. Thanks!